# Prove an equation of affine space

Tags: linear-algebra

In affine space $\mathbb{R^n}$ there is subspace $L$ given by equation
\begin{equation}
c_1 x_1 + \ldots + c_n x_n + c_{n+1} = 0
\end{equation}
Also, there is given affine isomorphism $f: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$
\begin{equation}
f(x_1, \ldots ,x_n) = (a_{11} x_1 + \ldots + a_{1n} x_n + b_1, \ldots , a_{n1} x_1 + \ldots + a_{nn} x_n + b_n)
\end{equation}
Prove that image of L in isomorphism f is given by equation
\begin{equation}
det
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \ldots & a_{1n} & b_1 - x_1 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \ldots & a_{2n} & b_2 - x_2 \\
\ldots &\ldots &\ldots &\ldots &\ldots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \ldots & a_{nn} & b_n - x_n \\
c_1 & c_2 & \ldots & c_n & c_{n+1} \\
\end{vmatrix}=0
\end{equation}

I would very much like to give some draft of my solution, but unfortunately I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear to me. What does "Prove that the image of $L$ in isomorphism $f$" mean?

Comment: @HowDoIMath Correcting it atm, I meant proving that L is given by this equation